# Why can't Node.js server read CSS if it is located on the higher lever than HTML?

Tags: css, node.js

For some reason, I can only access my CSS files in my Node.js app if they are located in the same folder or deeper than HTML.

Folder structure that works:

[image: Folder structure that works]

I can assess CSS here using the `css/style.css` path as it is located in the sub-folder of the HTML folder. It also works for the nested sub-folders.

Folder structure that doesn't work:

[image: Folder structure that doesn't work]

But when I try to move CSS on the level higher, it can't be accesses using `../css/style.css`, an error message about the incorrect MIME type (text/html) appears and the style doesn't apply.

Am I missing something or this is intended?

Comment: What is your `express.static()` ?

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/html')))`
And I want to locate my CSS to `public/css`. The page itself (html) loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with path, it must be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
```

Comment: It's exactly what I wrote. It doesn't work for some reason. For the usual front-end project - yes. But not for Node. I copy the same files in the same folder structure - doesn't work. 
Returns error `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:5000/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled`  and the style doesn't apply.